# Mock Generic Repository with contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a generic repository for several contexts. I can extend it and use it for services without problem. However, When I mock it, `this.Entities` in the constructor is always `null`.

**GenericDataRepsository**

```
public class GenericDataRepository<T, C> : IGenericDataRepository<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext, new() {

    protected C context;
    protected IDbSet<T> Entities;

    public GenericDataRepository() {
        this.context = new C();
        this.Entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public GenericDataRepository(C context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Entities = context.Set<T>();  // Problem is here. Entities didn't get set when mocking
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
        return Entities.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    // omitted Add, Update, Delte
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
 [Test]
    public void GetBIlloTo() {
        var data = new List<BillTo> {
            new BillTo { CONTACTID = 12, COUNTRY = "USA" }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<BillTo>, IQueryable<BillTo>>();

        ((IQueryable<BillTo>)mockSet).Provider.Returns(data.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<BillTo>)mockSet).Expression.Returns(data.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<BillTo>)mockSet).ElementType.Returns(data.ElementType);
((IQueryable<BillTo>)mockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = Substitute.For<MyEntities>();
        mockContext.BillToes.Returns(mockSet);
        var repo = new GenericDataRepository<BillTo, MyEntities>(mockContext);

        //// Act
        var actual = repo.FindBy(r => r.CONTACTID == 12);

        //// Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual.Count(), 1);
    }
```

**MyEntities** - generated by EF and I didn't change it.

```
 public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BillTo> BillToes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF database first, NUnit, and Nsubstitute. Tried Moq as well, same problem. So, Why didn't `Entities` get set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set your mock object to return any value using the method `set<T>`.

Just add the following call before you initialize your class under test:

```
mockContext.Set<BillTo>().Returns(mockSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why have a FindBy method at all?  Why not have a FindAll() that returns the the         this.Entities = context.Set() something like

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
{
    return _context.Set<T>());
}
```

Then the user of the repository can tack on any linq predicate they want
and you can mock or fake the FindAll() method to return whatever list of entities you want.

Comment: there's something to be said here about limiting your api and the leakyness of the IQueryable interface, but this way works I guess